# Null type schema in spark-salesforce connector

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, salesforce

I have a **Dataset< Row>** with 48 columns imported from Salesforce:

```java
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read()
  .format("com.springml.spark.salesforce")
  .option("username", prop.getProperty("salesforce_user"))
  .option("password", prop.getProperty("salesforce_auth"))
  .option("login", prop.getProperty("salesforce_login_url"))
  .option("soql", "SELECT "+srcCols+" from "+tableNm)
  .option("version", prop.getProperty("salesforce_version"))
  .load()
```

Columns contain `null` as well.
I need to store this Dataset in a **.txt** file and delimited by `^`.
I tried to store is as text file using:

```java
finalDS.coalesce(1).write().option("delimiter", "^").toString().text(hdfsExportLoaction);
```

But I got error:

```java
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Try to map struct<Columns....>to Tuple1, but failed as the number of fields does not line up.;
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveDeserializer$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$ResolveDeserializer$$fail(Analyzer.scala:2320)
```

I tried:

```java
finalDS.map(row -> row.mkString(), Encoders.STRING()).write().option("delimiter", "^").text(hdfsExportLoaction);
```

but the delimiters are vanishing and all the data is getting written concatenated.

I then tried to save as csv (just to make it work):

```java
finalDS.coalesce(1).write().mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).option("header", "true").option("delimiter", "^").option("nullValue", "").csv(hdfsExportLoaction+"/"+tableNm);
```

and:

```java
finalDS.na().fill("").coalesce(1).write().option("delimiter", "^").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).csv(hdfsExportLoaction);
```

but then it complained that

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: CSV data source does not support null data type.
```

Nothing is working.
When trying to write as a text file, then either the delimiter is getting removed, or the error that **only single column can be written to text file**,
When trying to write as a CSV, then **Null data type is not supported** exception.

Comment: With the new information it is clearly a bug in the connector  you use. While you can try to find a workaround (detecting columns with `NullType` and casting these explicitly might work), it should really be addressed by the author(s) of the connector. I edited the question to include the information you provided, but it would be great if you could provide output from `df.printSchema()` as well.

Comment: @ user10465355 you were correct. As you mentioned `lit(null)` introduced issue, I chnged it to `lit("null")` ("Null" as a text), and it worked. Now I am able to save as CVS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a problem in the dataset or dataframe itself. For me

```
df.coalesce(1).write.option("delimiter", "^").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).csv("<path>")
```

this worked as expected.Its properly delimited with "^". I would suggest inspect the data of your dataframe or datasets and the operations you are doing into it. Before writing the data use df.count once and see its failing or not

Comment: You must not be having a `null` in your data, that is why its working. Try inserting `null` in your columns and then save the csv. Let me know if it works.

Comment: I have null data in my case too. A column having Null and String value see the output

Comment: 1^^1548944642^true
1^29950529^1548937685^true

Comment: I analyzed the data...in my case the `null` is actually a string`"null"`. How should I resolve this ?

Comment: even if it is  String, It will not effect. Spark-csv works in all the scenarios

Comment: I was adding a column `.withColumn(newCol, functions.lit(null))`. This `null` was creating problem. I changed this to `.withColumn(newCol, functions.lit("null"))` and it worked.